# Unable to upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04.4 LTS, but upon running the software updater, it only gives me the option to upgrade to 21.10 and not 22.04 LTS. I have tried both the command line and the GUI ways, but to no avail. Most online guides say that to upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04 before August, you need to set the Software & Updates application to check for any new version, instead of just LTS, is this true, and can I upgrade without losing my files to 22.04 right now?

Comment: That is expected behavior as that's what is currently available.  I'd suggest reading the answer I provided in the tagged question; as it described [*very briefly*] the two upgrade files managed by the *Ubuntu Release Team* that describe what you're seeing... You can use the links I used to help yourself understand what you're seeing, which **IS EXPECTED and DOCUMENTED behavior**

Comment: When the *Ubuntu Release Team* decide the upgrade path is *safe* for existing users, in prior cycles (16.04->18.04 & 18.04->20.04) they've allowed a HOWTO Ubuntu blog to be published which tells people how to do it if they don't want to wait... It's not *ready* for that yet, with *known* & *documented* issues that 22.04 users will experience; that 20.04 currently does not have.. thus I'd wait if you can for now.   (FYI: the issues in 22.04 are *minor* and won't impact most users, but if impacted they may **not** be minor to you...  If you wait you needn't experience them)

Comment: @guiverc ok thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently there are some bugs that will take a couple of days to fix for the 20.04 to 22.04 update to work so it is disabled.
I wanted to check out one of my systems today so updated 20.04 to 21.10 then updated 21.10 to 22.04